# Code execution after this.close call on winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a winform, I have a method which calls `this.Close` and some lines of code follows within the method. Now since the method is not `static`, is it guaranteed that those lines of code will be executed? Those lines do not use any resources from the current instance of the winform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by handling the [Form.FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event.

Run the code you need from here and it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your Main-Form, which is called by the Program.cs you can copy the lines of code ater the `this.Close()` into your Program.cs

This looks like:

```
...
Application.Run(new frmMain());
// Your code here
...
```

Comment: A viable solution, however did not answer questions raised.

Answer (score 0):

In short: No.  If left the way it is, each time after calling `this.Close` there will be a race to see if the immediately following lines of code can be executed before the `Close` command removes them from memory.  It would be better to do run these lines of code elsewhere.  Think about it, do they REALLY need to be executed AFTER closing the form?  If so, you could always put them in another class, or in a `FormClosed` event, etc.

Comment: _"after calling this.Close there will be a race to see if the immediately following lines of code can be executed before the Close command removes them from memory"_ - source? You cannot set `this = null` in a method, also `Dispose()` doesn't render an object unusable, so despite whatever method you call on an object, the object will still be alive after that.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just assumed that that is what happens. In my experience at least, trying to call anything from a form that is not open will cause all kinds of problems, including not calling everything, mysterious unexplainable errors, crashes, and so on.

Comment: In my experience the method in a form class that calls `this.Close()` or `this.Dispose()` will perfectly run to its end. You can't access the form parts of the form anymore though, as _those_ will logically be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the body of Form.Close method:

```
public void Close() {
  if (base.GetState(262144)) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ClosingWhileCreatingHandle", new object[]       {
            "Close"
        }));
  }
  if (base.IsHandleCreated) {
    this.closeReason = CloseReason.UserClosing;
    base.SendMessage(16, 0, 0);
    return;
  }
  base.Dispose();
}
```

You can see in the end it is disposing the Form itself, but it is not terminating thread or something like that. So my money is the lines will always execute (unless they're touching member fields that can be already disposed after Form.Close(). But there are more elegant ways how to do it (see other answers).